# Android - Image in webview is not fit screen

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I want to fit images on screen which are coming from webservice and viewed on webview.

I successed for videos and they can fit screen.

This is css code;

```
<style type="text/css">

    iframe {
        display: block;
        max-width:100%;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        max-width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-size: cover;
        width: auto !important;
        resize:both;
        background:no-repeat fixed;
    }

</style>
```

I tried lots of things on css code based on google search but I couldn't make it fit the screen.

Then I add this css to webview content.

```
    String str = "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
            "    iframe {\n" +
            "        display: block;\n" +
            "        max-width:100%;\n" +
            "        margin-top:10px;\n" +
            "        margin-bottom:10px;\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    img {\n" +
            "            display: block;\n" +
            "            margin-top:10px;\n" +
            "            margin-bottom:10px;\n" +
            "            max-width:100%;\n" +
            "            height:100%;\n" +
            "            background-size: cover;\n" +
            "            width: auto !important;\n" +
            "            resize:both;\n" +
            "            background:no-repeat fixed;\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</style>"+currentNews.getContent();
```

Then I load view ;

```
content.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I only achieved non scaled form or cropped version. Thanks in advance.

[image: this is non-scaled version]

Comment: Still anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found what the problem is. Appearently my html data was getting another css styles at the server side.

So to be able to force it to use my style I've used `!important` for my css attributes. It is very good feeling when it works perfectly.

```
<style type="text/css">
iframe {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    }

</style>
```

Then I paste that style into a string variable which is `str` and I also add the other html data to `str` string variable. Then I load the html like below.

```
content.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

So the trick was just `!important` !